# .NET EventWaitHandle signal all threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, event-wait-handle

Will `close()` signal all the `threads` that have called `WaitOne()`?

If not, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will cause an `AbandonedMutexException`. The correct way of using this class is not to call close while waiters are active.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx

Comment: So if I have threads that are waiting, and I want to terminate for some reason, whats the best way to wake up the threads?  If I use set, it just wakes up ONE...

Comment: That exception is highly specific to the Mutex class.  Raised when the thread that owned the mutex terminated without releasing the mutex.

Comment: @HansPassant I actually looked it up - it also applies to the EventWaitHandle class.

Comment: I'm quite sure about this.  Feel free to document your answer appropriately.

Comment: The docs state the exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx (have not tested this).

Answer (score 1):

No.  It will cause the WaitOne() method to fail with an exception, ObjectDisposedException in particular.

The only "best way" is to not do this, it is a plain bug.  EventWaitHandle objects should only ever be closed or disposed when they are no longer used.